# repeated CSS background scales on mobile devices and shows moiré

Tags: css, background, repeat

I have a problem with a background. The image to be used is a 2x2px png with transparency, which is being repeated to give a pattern.
Works fine on large screens and phones but it gets screwed up on my Nexus7, showing a kind of moiré. Obviously the picture is being scaled somehow, I just don't know why.

My CSS:
    `background: url(pattern.png) repeat top left;`

I also tried:
    `background: url(pattern.png) repeat 2px;`

and i set the viewport like this:
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

There is another website that shows the same problem (at least on my tablet): http://hansimglueck-burgergrill.de/

Comment: could it be moire' produced inside your screen? I have an old television that does the same thing where a newer model doesn't show moire', both showing the same broadcast.

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware problem. I am testing on the Google Nexus7 and I've never heard of anything like that.

Comment: I would suggest you just make the bg image larger (that is, include a few repeats of the pattern in the actual image) to save the browser doing so much work to repeat the image across the screen. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. Didn't do the trick, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old. Maybe someone's finding this though.
Modern screens often have a higher pixel density, thus interpolate pictures to, let's say, 1.6 times the size for a sharper retina-like display. The pattern I used got split up in sub-pixels and therefore showed the Moiré. Hope this helps people.